# EC2 to S3 Upload Wrong Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload files from my EC2 Instance in US-EAST-1 to an S3 Bucket in US-EAST-1 but when I use the Java SDK but using Scala:

```
//create AWS credentials class\
  val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
  //Create connection to S3
  val conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
```

and try and put my file in:

```
conn.putObject(bucket, sourceSystems(i) + "/" + fileName, fileToUpload)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 [s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx] failed: connect timed out
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 [s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxx] failed: connect timed out
```

Why is it default trying to load to US-WEST-1 when the EC2 instance is in US-EAST-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region `us-east-1` is the default region. If  it is trying to connect to `us-west-1` then you have changed the default region settings. Since you don't show the region being set in your code I assume it is being set via config file in `~/.aws` or via an environment variable.

You can read about AWS SDK configuration settings [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence).

Comment: Just like to complement by saying that the Access Key and Secret key should not be hard coded. You should either load them from the ~/.aws/credentials or, if you are running your code in a EC2 instance, use IAM Roles

Comment: Is there a way in my code to specify the region? I can't find more relevant information that has it.

Comment: @theMadKing I'm really surprised you can't find any relevant information regarding that. What did you search for? I suggest reading this article: https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2IHRMVOFHSUO1/Working-with-Different-AWS-Regions

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behavior when upgrading from the `aws-java-sdk:1.10.46` to `aws-java-sdk:1.11.49`.

Note, that we are explicitly not configuring a region in either the java code or in the `~/.aws` directory. And we are running the process under a user with no userhome directory.

Further I whole heartedly disagree that `us-east-1` is the default region for the java sdk. I suggest that it is infact `us-west-1`, as given here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L4466